# What are the actual character limits for Google Chart QR codes?

Tags: qr-code, google-visualization

I've written some code that outputs the minimum numbers of pixels required to accommodate a standards compliant QR code given the characters to be encoded, the required margin, and EC Level.  However, I'm getting blank image responses from Google instead of valid QR Codes.

The smallest QR Code possible is a 29x29 pixel Version 1 QR Code (21 coded modules + 4 module margin on each side).  [example](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=29x29&cht=qr&chl=0&chld=H%7C4&choe=UTF-8)

[image: 1 char QR code]

According to the [Google Charts QR code documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes#details) the maximum number of 0-9 digits you can have in the Version 1 QR Code at EC Level H is 17.  However, specifying the parameters as such [results in a blank image](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=29x29&cht=qr&chl=12345678901234567&chld=H%7C4&choe=UTF-8); no matter what the `choe` parameter is set to; because there is more data being encoded than can fit.

[image: Should be valid but blank]

Reducing the number of characters to 14 [results in a valid QR code](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=29x29&cht=qr&chl=12345678901234&chld=H%7C4&choe=UTF-8).

[image: Must reduce digits to work]

So, does anyone have any idea how much data can be encoded by the Google Charts API at each given Version and EC Level?  Is it character byte dependant?  My code is written in Java, but a solution in any programming language, if required, would suffice.

Hopefully I've done something wrong, or there is some logic that can be followed, instead of it being a "good enough" implementation of QR Codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official answer to this.  As the API is now deprecated, it's unlikely that an answer will ever surface or the bug will ever be fixed.  You're better off using [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) instead as it's still developed and doesn't suffer from the mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the generated image in pixels is not relevant here. All of the QR codes you are seeing and generating are valid.

A Version 1 QR code can fit 17 digits, using Numeric mode, yes.

I think the Chart Server implementation is simply wrong here. It is using Numeric mode, but is putting in more padding bytes than I believe are necessary, which makes it use Version 2.

The version you see in [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) is actually the same base encoder code, but I think it is actually more up-to-date and perhaps fixed than this implementation, which originated in 2006. (I don't know though, no longer on the inside there.)

UTF-8 is valid if you use an ECI segment to specify UTF-8 encoding in Byte mode. But that's very rarely done right. zxing supports it.

In practice, you find all kinds of stuff put into QR codes in Byte mode -- Shift_JIS, UTF-8, more. zxing (and others) will guess it correctly a lot of the time. The Chart Server, AFAIK, will use UTF-8 when it has to, because it can't be legally encoded in the default of ISO-8859-1. That's not the issue here though.

I think the Chart Server is off a few bytes from the limits the spec states. The spec is ISO 18004:2006. It gives you all the right limits for all the versions, modes and EC levels.

AFAIK zxing does it right and it is Java.

Comment: Your credentials lead me to believe it's unlikely I'll get a better answer than yours. Unfortunately it doesn't provide the info I was after. The pixels are relevant to show that there should be an image showing. And all of the above qr codes should be valid, but aren't. 1 blank and 2 anti-aliased images are not valid qr codes. I've been using the data from the specs, but still get blank or miss-sized images from Google in what should be different modes. I was hoping someone could tell me Google's rules, rather than the spec. Now the api is deprecated, I guess I should just use zxing instead.

Comment: FYI: Just discovered that only the 1 qr code above is invalid, the anti-aliasing was caused by my Chrome being zoomed in one level, which appears to be the only zoom in level where the code becomes unusable.

Comment: I don't get a blank image from your link, nor do I ever get aliasing.  The chart server doesn't anti-alias these AFAIK. I am using Chrome too. I imagine it's a local setting / network issue. You're not going to find the "rules" documented, as they should be equal to the spec. I know that code is old and don't expect that fixes from zxing got back into it, so would not be surprised if it's off by a byte or two. In fact I remember fixing something like this a long time ago. But, in the main, the Chart Server works correctly in my experience. Don't remember any significant bugs.

Comment: Apologies, I had removed some examples of double size (58x58) codes in my question before posting, however that link was still pointing a the double size image. So that link was showing a Version 2 QR Code, instead of the Version 1 it should be.  I've fixed the link which now reflects the blank image in my question.  See my previous comment about the anti-aliasing issue, which was a browser setting.  Hopefully it's now clear that the Google Chart API for QR Codes is broken or at least not standard, hence my desire to know how it's actually working.

Comment: Yes I see that now. 29x29 is too small to encode a version 2 QR code, which requires 33x33 (with quiet zone). So it's back to the same issue. I think this is quite a minor bug. The QR codes are entirely valid, they just have 1 extra padding byte. zxing ought to work OK for you.